# instructions/manual on auto launch/shutdown on EC2

Tags: ruby, deployment, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, capistrano

need pretty trivial task
i have server, which in crontab every night will run "something" what will launch new EC2 instance, deploy there code (ruby script), run it, upon completion of the script shutdown the instance.
how to do it the best?
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach that can accomplish this without any external computer/cron job:

EC2 AutoScaling supports schedules for running instances.  You could use this to start an instance at a particular time each night.

The instance could be of an AMI that has a startup script that does the setup and running of the job.  Or, you could specify a user-data script be passed to the instance that does this job for you.

The script could terminate the instance when it has completed running.

If you are running EBS boot instance, then `shutdown -h now` in your script will terminate the instance if you specify `instance-initiated-shutdown-behavior` of `terminate`.